# the efficiency of call(null) and call(window)

Tags: javascript

```
function sum (a, b, c, d) {
    return a+b+c+d;
}

var result = 0;
var start = new Date().getTime();

for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    result = sum.call(window, 1,2,3,4);       // 2446 ms
    //result = sum.call(null, 1,2,3,4);       // 260 ms
}

var dur = new Date().getTime() - start;
alert(dur);
```

In non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object(namely window object in browser). 
Here comes the question, just as the code above, why sum.call(null, 1,2,3,4) runs much faster than the sum.call(window, 1,2,3,4)??

Answer (score 3):

Not just calling with window scope, calling with any scope which has lots of members and properties will results in longer time.

Calling with null, according to the [ECMA 262 v5, 10.4.3](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3), will results the this pointer of function binds to the global.

This will result shorter time:

```
function sum (a, b, c, d) {
    return a+b+c+d;
}

var result = 0;
var start = new Date().getTime();

for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    result = sum.call({}, 1,2,3,4); //nearly half of the time(1607ms) which null costs(3478ms) for me.
}

var dur = new Date().getTime() - start;
alert(dur);
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum.call(null, 1,2,3,4);` or `sum.call(window, 1,2,3,4);`  both are same thing... you will be get in `this` as ref inside function.

```
sum.call(null, 1,2,3,4);

function sum (a, b, c, d) {
    console.log(this); // null in this variable
    return a+b+c+d;
}
```

If you need to use `ref` in function then pass in first param in `.call()` function.

***According your question `sum.call(null, 1,2,3,4);` will fast because `window` ref always big size from `null` that you have passed as function `ref` in loop***

and more efficient will be call function direct as

```
sum(1,2,3,4)
```

because it exclude reduce one global ref object from function call.

### [Speed test results demo](http://jsperf.com/call-param-test)

[image]

Comment: Would you care to link that jsperf test that you created, instead of posting a screenshot of it?

Comment: Just a side note that your case with `{}` is a bit more expensive because it creates a new object each time. If you move the object-creating `{}` literal into a pre-test code block (like `var someObj = {};` outside the test and then `.call(someObj, ...)`), then that case should be much closer to the `window` test time: http://jsperf.com/call-param-test/2